# htaccess tidy URL rule with querystring too

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I currently has a htaccess with the rule:-

```
RewriteRule ^events/day/([^/\.]+)/?$ events/day.php?day=$1 [L]
```

Which is making /events/day.php?day=september-02 into a nice tidy /events/day/september-02

However now I also want to include a query string at the end of the tidy URL and detect that too so:-

```
/events/day/september-02?mobile=true
```

would resolve to:

```
/events/day.php?day=september-02&mobile=true
```

However the query string portion won't always be there and sometimes could be `mobile=false`

Would be very grateful if anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the QSA-flag (query string append):

```
RewriteRule ^events/day/([^/.]+)/?$ events/day.php?day=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will preserve the query string.

Comment: Great stuff, such a simple solution too, will try and remember that flag. Thank you.